# expression must have pointer type error

Tags: c, pointers, expression

I looked at all the other answers about this on here but it didn't seem to apply to mine.

```
MY_STRUCT_LIST*  tempList = NULL ;
size_t cnt = my_Session->my_ListIndex.size();
int i = 0;

for(i=0; i < (int)cnt ; i++)
{
   tempList = my_Session->my_ListIndex[i];
   if(tempList->lListIndex == treeItem)
   {      
    my_Session->my_ListIndex->push_back(i);
    break;
   }
 }
```

Here:

`my_Session` is a pointer
`my_ListIndex` is a Vector pointer of `MY_STRUCT_LIST` type.
`lListIndex` and `treeItem` are the same type.

```
 Error: the second my_Session has 583 "expression must have pointer type"
```

But it is a pointer!

Comment: declaration of `my_Session` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_Session->my_ListIndex->push_back(i);
```

...tries to use `my_ListIndex` as a pointer, which it (according to the call to `size()` a few lines above) is not.

```
my_Session->my_ListIndex.push_back(i);
```

...works better.

Comment: Yes according to first expression `my_Session->my_ListIndex.size()` you are correct